# How to redirect console output to Qt status bar

Tags: c++, c, qt

I'm writing GUI using Qt and need to redirect console output to status bar. For parts where code is my own I am simply using `ui->statusBar->showMessage("hello")`. Problem comes when I have to use C and C++ code written by others. This code interacts through console. Is it possible to redirect all console output to Qt status bar? What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to read output from command line tool?

Comment: Only to show progress messages. Code I'm working is well split into functions and i wrap  them in GUI, but progress reports are all over the place and need to be displayed.

Comment: Are the reports coming from `stdout`? If so, use `QProcess::readAll()`.